# Laravel policies with middleware not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-7, laravel-middleware

I'm building a website in Laravel. I'm trying to allow the view/modification of a Model only to the user that created it. I registered the policy and use a middleware in the route to restrict the view/modification/delete/update operations but I'm always **unauthorized**.

**TrashPrivateReportPolicy:**

```php
class TrashPrivateReportPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    public function before(User $user){
        if($user->can('manage_all_projects')){
            return true;
        }
    }

    public function results(User $user, TrashPrivateReport $trash_private_report){
        return $user->reports()->map(function($report){$report->trash_report();})->contains($trash_private_report);
    }
}
```

**AuthServiceProvider**

```php
class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $policies = [
        //'App\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
        'App\TrashPrivateReport' => 'App\Policies\TrashPrivateReportPolicy',
    ];

  
    public function boot()
    {
        $this->registerPolicies();

        Gate::before(function($user,$ability){
            return $user->abilities()->pluck('name')->contains($ability);
        });

    }
}
```

routes: **web.php**

```php
Route::get('/trash_private_reports/results/{trash_private_report}','TrashPrivateReportController@results')->name('trash_private_reports.results')->middleware('can:results,trash_private_report');
```

So when I'm connected as a lambda user and want to see the page results
*'/trash_private_reports/results/id/'* access is forbidden.
The policy does not seems to be called. I tried dd(..) in the method of the policy and nothing happens.

### **I have already tried:**

**Changing the policies array to:**

> TrashPrivateReport::class => TrashPrivateReportPolicy::class

**Updating and clearing:**

> composer dump-autoload
>
> php artisan route:clear
>
> php artisan view:clear
>
> php artisan config:clear

Thank you for the help :)

Comment: is your controller method typehinting the model to allow for route model binding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:

I solved the problem by replacing **before** by **after**

```php
Gate::after(function($user,$ability){
            return $user->abilities()->pluck('name')->contains($ability);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
Route::get('/', [UserController::class, 'index'])->middleware('can:viewAny,' . \App\Models\User::class)
```

or

```
Route::get('/', [UserController::class, 'index'])->middleware('can:viewAny,App\Models\User')
```

My models is `App\Models\User`. I tested on Laravel 8.33.1.

Answer (score -1):

the second argument for `middleware` should the model.

```php
Route::get('/trash_private_reports/results/{trash_private_report}','TrashPrivateReportController@results')->name('trash_private_reports.results')->middleware('can:results,App\TrashPrivateReport');
```

Comment: Not seems to work. In this exemple there using the same syntaxe as me: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/policy-not-working-on-route-middleware-works-in-view

Comment: @Anaya what if you always return `true` in the `results` method?

Comment: ```php

public function results(User $user, TrashPrivateReport $trash_private_report){
        dd("hello");
        return true;
    }

```

nothing happens, the dd is not triggered

Comment: It seems like the policy is never called, I think it is not correctly registered or maybe not correctly used with the middleware

Comment: the second parameter to the `can` middleware is the route parameter to use, if there is no model instance to use with the policy you would use the class name